# How can I fix get trackbar position error in pycharm?

Tags: python

I'm running opencv course on win10 using pycharm
I have copied the code provided in the free site, but it seems that the python version of the code is too old.
when running the code I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\OpemcvPython\testZone.py", line 56, in
>
> h_min = cv2.getTrackbarPos("Hue Min","TrackBars") cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.3)
> C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-1i5nllza\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window_w32.cpp:2577:
> error: (-27:Null pointer) NULL window: 'TrackBars' in function
> 'cvGetTrackbarPos'

I don't have the option to use sudu command and the only way I can change opencv packages is via pycharm setting
the code:

````
import numpy as np
path = 'C:/Users/User/OneDrive - Bio Milk Ltd/Desktop/DAPI.png'
def empty(a):
    pass


def stackImages(scale, imgArray):
    rows = len(imgArray)
    cols = len(imgArray[0])
    rowsAvailable = isinstance(imgArray[0], list)
    width = imgArray[0][0].shape[1]
    height = imgArray[0][0].shape[0]
    if rowsAvailable:
        for x in range(0, rows):
            for y in range(0, cols):
                if imgArray[x][y].shape[:2] == imgArray[0][0].shape[:2]:
                    imgArray[x][y] = cv2.resize(imgArray[x][y], (0, 0), None, scale, scale)
                else:
                    imgArray[x][y] = cv2.resize(imgArray[x][y], (imgArray[0][0].shape[1], imgArray[0][0].shape[0]),
                                                None, scale, scale)
                if len(imgArray[x][y].shape) == 2: imgArray[x][y] = cv2.cvtColor(imgArray[x][y], cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
        imageBlank = np.zeros((height, width, 3), np.uint8)
        hor = [imageBlank] * rows
        hor_con = [imageBlank] * rows
        for x in range(0, rows):
            hor[x] = np.hstack(imgArray[x])
        ver = np.vstack(hor)
    else:
        for x in range(0, rows):
            if imgArray[x].shape[:2] == imgArray[0].shape[:2]:
                imgArray[x] = cv2.resize(imgArray[x], (0, 0), None, scale, scale)
            else:
                imgArray[x] = cv2.resize(imgArray[x], (imgArray[0].shape[1], imgArray[0].shape[0]), None, scale, scale)
            if len(imgArray[x].shape) == 2: imgArray[x] = cv2.cvtColor(imgArray[x], cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
        hor = np.hstack(imgArray)
        ver = hor
    return ver

cv2.namedWindow("TrackBars")
cv2.resizeWindow("TrackBars", 640, 240)
cv2.createTrackbar("Hue Min","TrackBars", 0, 179, empty)
cv2.createTrackbar("Hue Max","TrackBars", 19, 179, empty)
cv2.createTrackbar("Sat Min","TrackBars", 110, 255, empty)
cv2.createTrackbar("Sat Max","TrackBars", 240, 255, empty)
cv2.createTrackbar("Val Min","TrackBars", 153, 255, empty)
cv2.createTrackbar("Val Max","TrackBars", 255, 255, empty)

imgOriginal = cv2.imread(path)
width, hight = 600, 600
dsize = (width, hight)

while True:
    img = cv2.resize(imgOriginal, dsize)
    imgHSV = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    h_min = cv2.getTrackbarPos("Hue Min","TrackBars")
    h_max = cv2.getTrackbarPos("Hue Max","TrackBars")
    s_min = cv2.getTrackbarPos("Sat Min","TrackBars")
    s_max = cv2.getTrackbarPos("Sat Max","TrackBars")
    v_min = cv2.getTrackbarPos("Val Min","TrackBars")
    v_max = cv2.getTrackbarPos("Val Max","TrackBars")
    print(h_min, h_max, s_min, s_max, v_min, v_max)
    lower = np.array([h_min,s_min,v_min])
    upper = np.array([h_max,s_max,v_max])
    mask = cv2.inRange(imgHSV, lower, upper)
    imgResult = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)
 #   cv2.imshow("Result", imgResult)
    imgStack = stackImages(0.6,([img,imgHSV],[mask,imgResult]))
    cv2.imshow("Stacked Images", imgStack)
    cv2.waitKey(1) ```
Thanks for your help
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removing the opencv 4.53.x version and installing the 4.5.1.x version solved that issue. Also for some reason had to change file location.